# TableView, apagar célula mas não a secção

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho uma tableView onde gostaria de apagar as células das secções sendo que, se for a última, em vez de apagar a secção também, queria que adicionasse uma nova célula com uma nova string: @"não existem células nesta secção". Por alguma razão o código abaixo não está a funcionar.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 3;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSMutableArray *spotType = [self spotsWithSection: section];

return spotType.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

NSMutableArray *thisSpotContainer = [self spotsWithSection:section];
Spot *s = (Spot*)thisSpotContainer[row];
cell.textLabel.text = s.name;

return cell;
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSMutableArray *thisSpotContainer = [self spotsWithSection: indexPath.section];

    if ([thisSpotContainer count] > 0) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [thisSpotContainer removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        if ([thisSpotContainer count] == 0) {

            NSArray *noSpotsHere = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This section has no spots.", nil];
            [thisSpotContainer insertObject:noSpotsHere atIndex:0];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }

        [tableView endUpdates];
    }

}

}

- (NSMutableArray*) spotsWithSection:(NSUInteger)section {

NSArray * Spots = [Spot allSpots];
NSPredicate *predicate;

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @"restaurant"];
        spotRest = [[Spots filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
        return spotRest;
        break;
    case 1:
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @"bar"];
        spotBar = [[Spots filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];            return spotBar;
        break;
    case 2:
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @"club"];
        spotClub = [[Spots filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
        return spotClub;
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Entendi que spotsWithSection é um array de array, assim, a quantidade de elementos dele indica a quantidade de seções e os arrays dentro deles, as linhas de cada seção. Porém, acho q vc errou aqui:    NSArray *noSpotsHere = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This section has no spots.", nil];
            [thisSpotContainer insertObject:noSpotsHere atIndex:0];   Vc está inserindo um array dentro do elemento 0 do thisSpotContainer  quando na verdade teria q inserir apenas o texto "This section has no spots."

Comment: Resumindo, apague  as linhas: NSArray *noSpotsHere = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This section has no spots.", nil];
            [thisSpotContainer insertObject:noSpotsHere atIndex:0];    e insira   [thisSpotContainer insertObject:@"This section has no spots." atIndex:0];

Comment: ah não ser q vc realmente esteja trabalhando com um array de 3 dimensões... Para eu entender melhor, vc poderia colocar o seu numberOfRowsInSection e numberOfSectionsInTableView e o cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: spotsWithSection é um array de objectos e a quantidade de elementos dentro dele indica o número de rows dessa secção. Tentei pôr a string no lugar do objecto mas continua a não adicionar.

Comment: Ele dá alguma mensagem de erro? O que é [self spotsWithSection: indexPath.section]; O certo não seria [self.spotsWithSection objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];   ?

Comment: [self spotsWithSection: indexPath.section] é um método que me retorna um array com os spots divididos por tipos, prontos a ser inseridos nas devidas secções: restaurante, bar ou club. Editei em cima.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro. mas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente, essas linhas não influenciam em nada:

```
 NSArray *noSpotsHere = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This section has no spots.", nil];
[thisSpotContainer insertObject:noSpotsHere atIndex:0];
```

Já que no cellForRowAtIndexPath vc está carregando o array novamente de algo q parece se um banco, sobrepondo o que vc inseriu nele.

O que vc pode fazer é, no commitEditingStyle após:

```
   [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

colocar:

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"This section has no spots.";
```

Porém, o outro problema é q se ocorrer um reloadData a linha irá sumir.

O que eu sugiro a fazer é colocar um reloadData após a exclusão:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
          NSMutableArray *thisSpotContainer = [self spotsWithSection: indexPath.section];
         if ([thisSpotContainer count] > 0) {
            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [thisSpotContainer removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            if ([thisSpotContainer count] == 0) {
                 [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
               cell.textLabel.text = @"This section has no spots.";
            }
         }
         [tableView endUpdates];
    }
    [tableview reloadData]
}
```

e:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    NSMutableArray *thisSpotContainer = [self spotsWithSection:section];
    if (thisSpotContainer.count == 0) {
       cell.textLabel.text = @"This section has no spots.";
    }else{
        Spot *s = (Spot*)thisSpotContainer[row];
        cell.textLabel.text = s.name;
    }
  return cell;
}
```

e no

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     NSMutableArray *spotType = [self spotsWithSection: section];
     int linhas = spotType.count;
     if (linhas == 0) {
        linhas = 1;
     }
     return linhas;
}
```

Comment: esqueci do numberOfRowsInSection, fiz uma edição. Estou respondendo sem o meu mac por perto, então pode ter algum erro.

Comment: A primeira opção funciona, no entanto a segunda ainda não. Será que pode postar o código commitEditingStyle com a segunda opção? De qualquer forma muito obrigada.

Comment: Colocado o commitEditingStyle